# Checking if a list object has been pressed?

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I am wondering if it is possible to run an if statement when a tab is pressed instead of directing to a new page in html. The if statement would be so if true display certain tab within the form.

```
    <nav id="profiletabs">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li><a href="#bio" class="sel">Bio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#activity">Activity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#friends">Friends</a></li>
      <li><a href="./usersettings.php">Settings</a></li>
```

So when one of these are pressed, check which has been then run statement. Thanks will appreciate any guidance on if this is even possible.

Comment: I guess [JQuery TABS](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) is what you are looking for? You can still add functionality by using ajax to load content etc.. But you get the idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use bootstrap tabs if you are using bootstrap in your project. Look at this example from the official website:

```
    <div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is the tutorial to get started with bootstrap tabs:

[Bootstrap Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Alternatively you can use jquery tabs.

Good Luck